# AngularJS - directive components dropdown not getting initialized for edit

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to Angular JS. 
What I am trying to do is create a reusable component using Directive. As of now it just has one drop-down. While doing Add the drop-down is getting populated with the values in permissionValues array and binding with the empty model with the selected value is happening. But when I try to Edit the drop-down is not getting initialized with existing model value value. 
The directive code.

```
  directive('userPermissions', function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template:'<div><select ng-model="ngModel" ng-options="abc [optValue] as abc [optDescription] for abc in array"></select>{{tab}}</div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope:{ ngModel: '=', tab:'='},
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.optValue = attrs.optValue;
            scope.optDescription = attrs.optDescription;
            scope.$watch(attrs.array, function(newVal, oldVal){
                 if(newVal != oldVal){
                     scope.array = newVal;
                 }
            });
        }
      };
    });
```

The HTML code

```
                <user-permissions  tab="tab"  
                    ng-model="newUser.canCheckout1" 
                    array="permissionValues" 
                    opt-value="value" 
                    opt-description="label"></user-permissions>
```

in main controller

```
 $scope.permissionValues = [{label:'Standard', value:'true'},{label:'Restricted', value:'false'}];
```

As you can see I have add "tab" for testing. I am changing the value of tab on load function which is getting called when I click on Edit. New value of tab is getting printed but the drop-down is not getting initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to two-way bind your `array` attribute from the controller using:

```
scope: {array: '=' ... }
```

The problem is that you don't have any `$scope.array` in your controller.  So you need to somehow link the two.  try this:

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.optValue = attrs.optValue;
    scope.optDescription = attrs.optDescription;
    scope.array = scope.$eval(attrs.array);
}
```

This will work but wouldn't create dynamic binding.  It will only read the value once and then it won't be updated if the `scope[attrs.array]` ever changes.  In order to do that, you'd have to do a `$watch` to listen for changes:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.array, function(newVal, oldVal){
     if(newVal != oldVal){
         scope.array = newVal;
     }
});
```

Hope that helps.

UPDATE:

To clarify, there are multiple ways to do this, so its up to you for how you want to do it.  But the idea behind the `scope: { ... }` binding in a directive is that you're specifying which properties of the scope you want to be bound and how you want them bound (one-way or two-way).  You were telling angular to bind the `$scope.array` property from your controller into your directive.  But because there wasn't any `$scope.array` property, nothing was being bound.  So you can either change your binding to say `scope: {permissionValues: '='}` or you can change your `$scope.permissionValues` in your `controller` function to be `$scope.array`.  Either should work.

But since you're trying to use the `array="permissionValues"` attribute on your directive to signify which `$scope` property to use, I figured you would want to do it the way I specified above.  Using `scope.$watch` means you don't have to use any `scope: { ... }` binding at all.  The `$watch` function manually creates that binding for you and allows you to use the `attrs.array` value to dynamically bind to the proper scope parameter at runtime.  Using `scope: {}` requires that you know what the scope property is called when the directive is created, and not when it is read from the DOM.

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Hi Tennisgent, thanks for your response. You are right I do not have $scope.array in my controller. should I add both scope.array and watch? I tried adding each individually but it's not working. If I add watch on attrs.array I should modify array on edit for watch to execute right? What I am doing right now on click of edit I am initializing the model value of cancheckout1 in main controller. I am not sure How can I initialize array from main controller. Feel free to suggest any other way of creating reusable drop-down.

Comment: Added more of an explanation.  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I understood the concept but somehow it's still not working. If I have understood correctly I don't need array in scope:{}. I have edited the code in question section, but after making this change nothing is getting populated in drop-down what I am getting is a blank drop-down. but if I add array variable in scope:{} it at least lists two options but does not preselect any thing based on model value. I am new to angular so please pardon me if my question sound silly.